# Creating a small data pipeline

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, amateur-observing, radio-astronomy, fits

I wanted to create a small data pipeline such that it consists of images of sky in the filters  F125W, F160W, F606W and F850LP. The 4 images for a single object should be in a single FITS File which is later to be used for analysis purposes. An example of what I want this data pipeline to resemble could be found here<sup>1</sup>

Can anyone please outline a way for me to do this ?

---

<sup>1</sup> https://drive.google.com/file/d/16y2oYZU_R8BJFUNs_73UNMjiDbe6m2H3/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Fits is just a file format to store images with accompanying data, but it's not a 'pipeline'. That would be a collection of tools and related scripts used to process or transform data. Please consider this and revise your question to become more clear. You might want to look at astropy

Comment: Questions should be self contained - we don’t want to download data from random google drive links.

Comment: The link is a link to a fits file. As indicated in my previous comment: a file is not a data pipeline; it could be the output of one; but it doesn't tell us the inputs which generated it.